# Fresco with kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, popup, kotlin-android-extensions, fresco

I am trying to display a image popup in Kotlin and for that I am creating a dilog and set image from url using library fresco but I am getting error with syntax how should I do this below is my implementation.
I want to set onclick event too how to do that.

Comment: what is your error? Post the error logs

Answer (score 1):

Try this Because you are setting image before setting view and try with picaso and Glide its good for getting image with url

```
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_streak_homepopup, container, false)
val image = view.findViewById(R.id.streak_popup) as SimpleDraweeView
val uri: Uri = Uri.parse("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/fresco/master/docs/static/logo.png")
image.setImageURI(uri)
return View
```

Comment: how to handle onclick event If I have a deep link?

Comment: please try this one : https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking?authuser=1